# Simple extraction of final redirected URL with scrapy

Tags: scrapy

So I'm really struggling to do what should be a simple thing with Scrapy. I'm new to it, so that's a factor.

I'm trying to crawl a page that has a list of get.php? style links that resolve to a redirect on a different, external site. I'm only interested in initial links that match a regex, and I've been able to achieve the filtering using the code below. However, I cannot for the life of me find a way to extract the final, redirected destination URL.

I've tried several posts here and looked at LinkExtractor but nothing seems to be working for my use case (which I thought was simple). My script IS following the links because I can see it via the debug text.

I really thought that extracting a final URL would be easy with Scrapy but I'm now pulling my hair out and have a killer headache. I'll try again tomorrow but if anyone could offer some help in the meantime it would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to get a readout in JSON or just the console that shows me the original link and the final link.

The site itself is not particularly structured. It just has each hyperlink separated by a `<p>` tag.

```
from pathlib import Path

import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "text"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://testsite.com/page',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
    
        for next_page in response.css('a::attr(href)').re(r'.*regexgoeshere.*'):
            yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
            print("URL: " + next_page)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Do you mean the final link on each page?

Comment: @Alexander - I mean the URL it redirects to. I've since given up on scrapy to do this an am using BeautifulSoup instead along with Requests now to which is far more simple:

final = requests.get(query)
final.url


But I'll leave this post for anyone that has a scrapy related answer.

Comment: I still don't understand... What is wrong with using `response.url` ?

Comment: @Alexander - It didn't give me the address of the destination when a 302 redirect was in place.